# stof function is not declared in this scope c++

Tags: c++

When I compile my code,I got this error

### 'stof' was not declared in this scope.

and my code is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string str,str2;
cin>>str>>str2;
float a,b;
a = stof(str);  //error
b = stof(str2); //error
cout<<a+b;
return 0;
}
```

how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) is located in the standard C++ header `<string>`.

Comment: So I should change the header to #include<string> ?? If yes then it's also not working.

Comment: @Sam You must have C++11 enabled on your compiler.

Comment: @Sam Try compiling with the `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: What compiler are you using? There should be an place for specifying the program options.

Comment: I am using devc++ 5.2.0.3. On compiling using **-std=c++11** got this error **unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11'**.

Comment: @Sam Dev C++ probably doesn't support C++11. Upgrade your compiler to the latest versions of Clang or GCC.

Answer (score 4):

Also `std::stof` can only be compiled using c++11 version for which compilation should be done as:

```
g++ -std=c++11 code.cc
```

Answer (score 0):

With dev c++ you need to go to Project > Project Options (Ctrl +h) > Compiler > Code generation > Language standard and select GNU C++ 11

(Not too sure about the menu since i have the language set to italian but it's pretty much that)